# Markov Random Field Implementation

Tags: markov-random-field

Honestly, I'm having trouble understanding the general steps taken to actually use a Markov Random Field (MRF) in practice.

Here's my current thinking on what I would have to do in practice.

1. Specify a graph structure for the MRF based upon domain knowledge (which variables you think will be conditionally dependent upon each other)
2. Specify the potential functions so that they will be larger for combinations of variables that are more likely to go together. You can choose the potential functions to be almost anything you want? How do you find the weights in the potential functions?
3. Use your joint density function representation somehow. One example I've seen is to use observed random variables to infer things about unobserved random variables. If X and Y are in your graph and you observe X, you may want to find the value of Y that maximizes the distribution P(Y|X). You would maximize this using some sort of MAP estimator/algorithm?

Have I missed something? Am I misunderstanding what I'm supposed to do?